# Redistributing a WinForms component with design-time functionality in a separate DLL without admin rights

Tags: winforms, visual-studio, windows-forms-designer, design-time, elevated-privileges

I am trying to modify the installation package for one of our legacy WinForms component. The goal I want to achieve is to avoid elevating privileges and do all works without admin rights. The problem is that the component is implemented in two DLLs - the core functionality redistributed with compiled apps and the design-time functionality needed only for the WinForms designer. To provide all design-time features of the component, VS should "know" how to find the design-time DLL.

Earlier we created the corresponding records in the `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\.NETFramework\v2.0.50727\AssemblyFoldersEx` registry key, and this has been working ok for years - starting from VS 2005. However, we can't write to this registry key without admin rights. Other ways to do what I need are adding assemblies to GAC (using gacutil or from code using the System.EnterpriseServices.dll) or copying DLLs to the PublicAssemblies folder of VS, but they all require admin rights too.

Is there another reliable way to redistribute the design-time DLL without admin rights that works, at least, for all latest versions of VS starting from VS 2010?

Comment: As far as I know, VS 2017 looks only in its local installation folders (PublicAssemblies, PrivateAssemblies, etc) and the GAC to resolve these things. I have also gone through the pain of VSIX installer creation for VS 2017.

Comment: @FrankHileman, now, the aforementioned AssemblyFoldersEx registry key for .NET Framework 2.0 is still supported in VS 2017 - I have just checked that.

Comment: Interesting. I tried to use that for run-time and designer dlls. The run time is referenced by a item template. The run-time references the designer dll. Since our users can install multiple versions of these dlls, it is important that VS picks up the most recent. I could not make this happen without using the GAC. The registry location you mention was only good for add references. However it could be that the experimental instance is simply inconsistent... and I get different behavior at different times.

Comment: @FrankHileman, maybe, a late comment, but you can find some ideas how to resolve runtime references in [my question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56189207/how-winforms-propertygrid-finds-custom-type-converters-in-external-libraries) related to the use of the PropertyGrid control at run time.