# How WinForms PropertyGrid finds custom type converters in external libraries?

Tags: .net, winforms, propertygrid, design-time, uitypeeditor

We have a custom control. Some properties of this control use custom type converters and UI type editors, and they are implemented in a separate design-time DLL. These type converters are defined using the string syntax of the [`TypeConverter`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.typeconverterattribute) and [`Editor`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.editorattribute) attributes, for example:

```
[TypeConverter("<full class name>, <library name>, Version=<version>")]
public CustomType Property1
{
    // property implementation
}
```

When we display the properties of our custom control in the standard PropertyGrid control from the WinForms package in a compiled app, the corresponding type converters and UI type editors from our design-time DLL are found only when we place this DLL in the folder containing the application exe. We do not want to duplicate the design-time DLL in this folder for some reasons. Is there any other way to tell the PropertyGrid control where it can find the design-time DLL referenced this way?

Comment: This DLL needs to be found by Visual Studio's probing rules, very troublesome.  Only decent option is to put it in the GAC.  Note that [you already knew this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48766967/17034).

Comment: @HansPassant, my previous question concerned this topic was about the VS IDE, but now I am asking about the run time. Thought there could be any difference, especially looking at the fact that we are talking about the PropertyGrid control.

Comment: Use the AppDomain.AssemblyResolve event to help the CLR find the assembly at runtime.

Comment: @HansPassant you confirmed yourself that there is a difference wit the IDE :)
BTW, the AssemblyFoldersEx registry key and putting the design-time DLL into VS's PrivateAssemblies folder also do not work in the case of compiled exe. Add to all this that we deploy our app not under a user with admin privileges.

Comment: Look at the [<probing> Element](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/configure-apps/file-schema/runtime/probing-element) and [<codeBase> Element](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/configure-apps/file-schema/runtime/codebase-element) documentation and see if you can make that work for your usage case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use either of the following options:

- Install the assembly in GAC and decorate the property like this (use your assembly fully qualified name). As already mentioned in the comments by Hans, I also believe it's the most decent way:

  ```
  [TypeConverter("MyAssembly.MyClassTypeConverter, MyAssembly, Version=1.0.0.0," +
      " Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=8ac69aab03bb290e")]
  public MyClass MyClass { get; set; }
  ```
- Copy the assemblies to your application folder and decorate the property like this.

  ```
  [TypeConverter("MyAssembly.MyClassTypeConverter, MyAssembly")]
  public MyClass MyClass { get; set; }
  ```
- In case of having a known location for assemblies, you can handle [`AppDomain.AssemblyResolve`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.appdomain.assemblyresolve?view=netframework-4.8) event and load the assembly. For example, assuming there is an `assemblies` folder under your application folder which contains the assembly, you can add the following code to your main method before `Application.Run`:

  ```
  AppDomain.CurrentDomain.AssemblyResolve += (s, e) =>
      Assembly.LoadFrom(Path.Combine(Application.StartupPath,
          "assemblies", $"{e.Name}.dll"));
  ```

  I assume you have the property declaration:

  ```
  [TypeConverter("MyAssembly.MyClassTypeConverter, MyAssembly")]
  public MyClass MyClass { get; set; }
  ```
- As already mentioned in the comments by TnTinMn, In case of having a known location for assemblies, you can also load assemblies without writing code, by registering the known folder in your app.config using [`probing`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/configure-apps/file-schema/runtime/probing-element) tag or [`codebase`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/configure-apps/file-schema/runtime/codebase-element) tag. For example, assuming there is an `assemblies` folder under your application folder which contains the assembly:

  ```
  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <probing privatePath="assemblies"/>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
  ```

  I assume you have the property declaration:

  ```
  [TypeConverter("MyAssembly.MyClassTypeConverter, MyAssembly")]
  public MyClass MyClass { get; set; }
  ```

> **Note:** None of the above options need adding a reference to the assembly which contains the type converter.